# jQuery not removing class after being added through jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, removeclass

I seem to have run into a bit of trouble this morning with `removeClass`. First I click a `div` to add Class `'containerhover'`, then when I click the close button it will not remove the class that it has just added to the `div`.

I don't know if this has something to do with it being added to the dom only and not being actually coded into the HTML. Please can someone help.

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {

    $('.container').click(function(e) {
        var mythis = $(this);
        mythis.addClass("containerhover");
        mythis.find('.backface').addClass("bfhover");
        mythis.find('.album').addClass("ahover");
    });

    $('.closealbum').click(function(e) {
        $('.container').removeClass('containerhover');
    });
});
```

Comment: @roXon `.click(function)` is short for `.bind('click', function)`.

Comment: [Works well for me](http://jsfiddle.net/knCR8/).

Comment: Please post your actual code. The code you gave works properly.

Comment: This is one of those "is it plugged in" questions:  Are you sure the "Close Album" item has a class of "closealbum"?

Comment: do you know that your click function on .closealbum is being called? Throw in an alert() to find out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), to attach the event to the container, and activate it *only* if the `.closealbum` element is clicked. Also, add the `event.stopPropagation()` method to prevent the event from bubbling further:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.closealbum', function(e) {
    $('.container').removeClass('containerhover');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

1. Your problem is caused by the fact that the `.closealbum` element does not exist when binding the `click` event.
2. Your element is positioned inside the other element. Without `e.stopPropagation()`, the event bubbles up, and the first event will also be triggered, undoing the second event's removeClass.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/knCR8/1/

Comment: Very likely something along this line, so +1. But if the `.closealbum` is indeed nested, then likely that it should only affect the ancestor `.container` instead of all `.container` elements. So maybe `$(this).closest('.container').remove...`

Comment: I missed the part in the question where it was mentioned the closealbumn was added later.  This is correct.